# How to return an array from a Javascript Facebook API request?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hopefully there is an easy way to do this and my Javascript skills are just lacking. I am wanting to call a function that will get some Facebook posts, add them to an array and return to use elsewhere. Current code is below.

```
function GetFaceBookStream(name, max) {
    FB.init({ apiKey: 'removed for post' });
    var lastDate = '2011-04-29Z00:00:00';
    var faceBookArray = [];
    var faceBookString;        

    FB.api("/" + name + "/feed", { limit: max, since: lastDate }, function (response) {
        var sb = string_buffer();

        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var post = response.data[i];

            sb.append("<li class='facebook'>");
            sb.append("<img alt=\"Facebook\" src='Images\\Carousel\\fbIcon.png\' />");
            sb.append("<h4>FACEBOOK</h4>\n");
            sb.append("<div class=\"from-name\"><a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/#!/profile.php?id=" + post.from.id + "\">" + post.from.name + "</a></div>");
            sb.append("<div class=\"time\">" + post.created_time + "</div>");
            if (post.message != undefined) {
                sb.append("<div class=\"message\">" + post.message + "</div>");
            }

            sb.append("</li>stringSplitMarker");
        }

        faceBookString = sb.toString();
        faceBookArray = faceBookString.split('stringSplitMarker');            
    });

   return faceBookArray;
}
```

I realize this set up won't work due to variable scope in Javascript, but this is basically what I'm trying to achieve. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making an *asynchronous* AJAX request.
The callback only runs after your code finishes.

You need to pass the data back using a callback.

For example:

```
function GetFaceBookStream(name, max, callback) {
    ...
    FB.api(..., function(response) { 
        ...
        callback(something, else);
    });
}
```

You can call the function by supplying a callback to receive the response:

```
GetFaceBookStream(name, max, function(param1, param2) {
    //This code runs later and can use the response.
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway you could provide some added syntax to my code to illustrate how to do this correctly. I'm still not grasping how to callback this after doing some research.